# Javascript unit testing errors, stubbed function still being called

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, sinon

I am trying to write some unit tests and I am getting errors in the test and I am trying to understand why the errors happen.

The unit test is for the `index.ts` file that calls the `features/index.ts` file. I am stubbing the default export from `features/index.ts` with sinon. But when I run the tests I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined` pointing at the file `features/feature1.ts`

I have added the relavant extracts from the tests and typescript files below.

###### features/feature1.ts

```
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import {Setup} from "../types";

const TEMPLATE_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname,"../../templates");
const INDEX_TEMPLATE = fs.readFileSync(TEMPLATE_ROOT, "index.js"), "utf8");

export const setup: Setup = async ({config, options}) => {
  // Internal code removed
}
```

###### features/index.ts

```
import {setup as feature1} from "./feature1.ts";
import {setup as feature2} from "./feature2.ts";

type FeatureTypes = "feature1" | "feature2"

type Features = {
  [key in FeatureTypes]: Setup;
};

const features: Features = {
  feature1: feature1,
  feature2: feature2 
}

export default features
```

###### index.ts

```
import features from "./features"
import { Config, Options  } from "./types";

export async function init(config: Config, options: Options): Promise<void> {
  const nextFeature = options.features ? options.features.shift() : undefined;
  if (nextFeature) {

    // Other irrelevant code

    await Promise.resolve(features[nextFeature]({ config, options }));
    return init(config, options);
  }
}
```

###### index.spec.ts

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import * as sinon from "sinon";
import { init } from '.'
import * as features from "./features";
import { Config, Options  } from "./types"

describe("init", () => {
  const sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  let featuresStub: sinon.SinonStub;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    featuresStub = sandbox.stub(features, "default").returns({
      feature1: sandbox.stub().resolves(),
      feature2: sandbox.stub().resolves(),
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it("should call setup features", async () => {
    const setup: Setup = {
      features: [
        "feature1",
        "feature2",
      ],
    };

    await init({}, options);
    expect(featuresStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });

  // rest of tests
});
```

I have also tried the changing the stub setup to be:

```
import * as feature1 from ".features/feature1";
import * as feature2 from ".features/feature2";

// Other code

describe("init", () => {
  const sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  let feature1Stub: sinon.SinonStub;
  let feature2Stub: sinon.SinonStub;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    feature1Stub = sandbox.stub(feature1, "setup");
    feature2Stub = sandbox.stub(feature2, "setup");

    feature1Stub.resolves() 
    feature2Stub.resolves()
  });

  // Rest of code and tests
});
```

I don't know why it would be trying to run code `const TEMPLATE_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname,"../../templates");` if I have stubbed the function that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out the imports were wrong

```
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
```

should be:

```
import * as path from "path";
import * as fs from "fs";
```